# Rendering CSS on javascript print

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to print div contents, using javascript, but the problem is that the css style is not being rendered on print. The project is created using bootstrap studio, only that the print code is from somewhere else!

Here's a snippet of the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Form</title>
<script>
    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    {

        var mywindow = window.open('', 'printReport', 'height=500,width=700');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Form S11</title>');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"  media="print">');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700"  media="print">');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:300,400|Roboto:300,400,700"  media="print">');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:300,400"  media="print">');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Romanesco"  media="print">');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:300,400"  media="print">');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css"  media="print">');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../assets/css/FPE-Gentella-form-elements.css"  media="print">');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../assets/css/FPE-Gentella-form-elements1.css"  media="print">');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../assets/css/styles.css"  media="print">');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }
</script>
</head>
```

```
<button type="submit" class="print" onclick="PrintElem('#printReport')">Print</button>
<div id="printReport">
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 bg-primary">
                //div contents to to print
                ....
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</head>
</body>
```

Any idea on where i'm missing what?

Comment: I don't see your jQuery script tag. What does the console say?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `print()` immediately after filling popup's document with HTML and hence it starts before popup window page will be loaded completely.

You need to wait for document to be loaded completely (so all CSS will be applied). It can be accomplished either by injecting jQuery into popup's window and use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    window.print(); 
});
</script>
```

or, even better, use plain script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { 
    window.print(); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load a pre-made html file like this `var mywindow = window.open('printReport.html','_blank', 'height=500,width=700');` and then append the html you need on load.

In your html file you will declare all the stylesheets you need:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Form S11</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../assets/css/styles.css"  media="print">
  etc......
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="appendStuffHere"><!-- your content --></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried loading a premade html page, just as per your instructions, but still the css is not rendering

Comment: There are some rules that you should apply for printing pages like the `overflow:visible !important;`  rule inside the body declaration and any `position:absolute` values should be set to `position:relative` or position:static instead. If you are expecting the same layout as your webpage in print it's not gonna happen.